# Passwd tag getting changed to password automatically?

Tags: support

[In this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/227013/kali-linux-usb-persistence-cannot-change-root-password) user mentioned that he tried tagging an answer with [passwd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwd), but it got changed to [password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password) automatically. I tried re-tagging it with edit, but apparently I failed, too. Is this a bug, did someone decline my tag change, or am I just missing something simple?

Comment: Sounds like the tags have been made "synonyms", so the site automatically replaces it. I'd check, but not sure how to on mobile...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[passwd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwd) is [a synonym](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/password/synonyms) of [password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password). I don't know why it is so, but the behaviour you have seen is expected of synonyms.

Comment: Good to know new feature - never heard of synonyms; However, since passwd is tool for setting password, and password can refer to something else, I'm not sure if that's desirable behaviour. They even have different descriptions.

Comment: @MatthewRock if you want to argue the synonym, that belongs in another question.

Comment: Okay then. Thanks for information.

Comment: Note: [the synonym was removed](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/a/3623/23408) about 20 minutes after the above discussion occurred.