# Passwd tag synonymous to password?

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

Having found out in [this question](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/passwd-tag-getting-changed-to-password-automatically) that [password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/password) is synonym to [passwd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwd), I'd like to ask if that's intended behaviour? `passwd` refers to a tool; `password` should be a tag for questions that ask about passwords, password managers, password authentication, etc. They both have different descriptions and meanings; Sometimes you want to ask question that is specific to `passwd` tool, and sometimes your question refers to `passwords`, but not `passwd`. Plus, it's easier to navigate searching for `passwd`, when trying to solve related problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it was intended by the user who suggested it and the others who voted on it, but it does seem wrong to me, so I removed the synonym. It renamed [passwd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwd) 45 times since January 2014 though, and those won't automatically change back, so there's potentially some posts in that time frame that should be tagged [passwd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/passwd) but aren't.